# c++ | wxwidgets: functions associated with wxFileName not working

Tags: c++, function, file-io, wxwidgets

`Using GCC 4.6.2 and wxWidgets 2.8  under windows 7`

I am unable to get any of the functions associated with **wxFileName** to get working.

I have tried to include and link the

```
<wx/filename.h>
<wx/filefn.h>
```

and I am trying to implement:

```
//path = full path including file name
wxString dir = wxPathOnly(path);
wxString filename = wxFileNameFromPath(path);

wxFileName file_n = wxFileName(dir, filename); //---(1)
// or
wxFileName file_n = (dir, filename); //---(2)
// tried both (1) and (2)

wxString ext = wxT("~");
file_n.SetExt(var); // does not work??
```

EDIT: So the function `file_n.SetExt(var)` does not seem to work.

I get no errors during the compiling or linking process. Hence I am not sure what could be going wrong.

I have checked in the official documentation for the 2.8 version of wxwidgets but I cannot seem to see what seems to be the problem.

Comment: You don't even say what goes wrong, how are we supposed to tell you what do you need to make it right?

Comment: What are the values of path, dir, filename and file_n after you run this code?  What do you expect them to be?

Comment: @ravenspoint The value of `path` is actually extracted from `wxFileDialog` object's function `GetPath()` and the subsequent values are derived as shown above. So I am trying to convert any given file extension and replace it with `~` for e.g. `test.txt` to `test~`. But nothing happens at all and I don't even get any compile or link errors.

Comment: @VZ. Sorry for that if I was not clear about it. The function SetExt() does not work.

Comment: **UPDATE**: So I tried other functions like: `GetExt()`which works and `SetEmptyExt()` which does not seem to work.

Comment: Amazingly, you *still* don't say what's wrong. Hint: saying "does not work" is not enough.

Comment: @Raidri  Why did you edit this useless question?  Just close it, already!

Comment: @ravenspoint http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258176/remove-handling (and I did vote to close)

Comment: @Raidr  OK, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
wxString ext;
wxString one;
wxString two;
wxFileName::SplitPath("C:\report\setup.ini", &one, &two, &ext);
```

Comment: good to know that the class has not been abandoned. Apart from that it is still not working for me.

Comment: BTW, I'm using VS2010 and Win7